# MiniKF users provisioning phase fails

Tags: kubeflow

I'm trying to install MiniKF on my local Mac.
I followed the instructions listed [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/workstation/getting-started-minikf/).
After browsing to http://10.10.10.10 and progressing with the wizard, I'm getting this error message:

> An unexpected exception has occured
> Line: build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/rok_common/cmdutils.py:942
> Type: CommandExecutionError
> Reason: Command `<ExtCommand [TY2CSkwoO9o]` rok-gw --url http://10.10.10.10:8080/rok/ --username user bucket-create snapshots', status=FINISHED (ret: 1), PID=29432, shell=False>' failed. Error log: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/bin/rok-gw", line 11, in \n    sys.exit [...truncated...]  line 81, in login\n  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/rok_common/http.py", line 224, in raise_for_status\nrok_fort_client.client.FortClientError: 401 (Unauthorized) Error for 'POST [http://10.10.10.10:8080/rok/auth/v1/user/sessions'](http://10.10.10.10:8080/rok/auth/v1/user/sessions%27), API Error: unauthorized, code: 401, msg: Invalid user credentials, details: This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested\n
> The logfile `/home/vagrant/provision.log' may contain more information on this error, including a backtrace.
> *** MiniKF provisioning tool terminated. Press Enter to restart, Ctrl-C to exit... ***

This error can be seen in the picture below.

When I'm clicking "Connect to Kubeflow" and entering the username and password as seen in the picture below, I'm getting the error: "Invalid Email Address and password.".

Any ideas how to fix that?
[image: Kubeflow installation error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by deleting the vdi file (minikf-user-data.vdi) and running these commands again:

```
vagrant init arrikto/minikf
vargant up
```